# printing structs in C++

Tags: c++, printing

I'm trying to print 3 attributes from a struct.  Why won't they all print? They will print 2 at a time, but not all three together.

Comment: left out semicolon at the end of the cout statement up there.  But I have it in my code.

Comment: Why isn't `items` declared as an array?

Comment: Sorry I did declare it as ItemStack *items=null-ptr;  Then I had two functions to read from two files and load data into the struct.

Comment: How about, you know, showing your actual code? Code you made up just for this post isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: Don't put corrections in comments, click the "edit" link and fix the question.

Comment: Why did you delete the example code? The way it stands know, the question is pretty useless?

Answer (score 3):

`name` has a Carriage Return character at the end. So it's printing

```
2HP Potion\r10
```

`\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line, without moving to the next line, so `10` overwrites `2H`.

I suspect this is because you read the name from a file that was written on Windows, which uses `\r\n` as its line break sequence in text files. You should either fix the file using `dos2unix`, or change the code that reads the file to remove `\r` characters.

You can remove the `\r` at the end with:

```
int last_pos = name.size()-1;
if (last_pos >= 0 && name[last_pos] == '\r') {
    name.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: how do you get rid of carriage return in name?

Comment: `name[strlen(name)-1] = 0`.

Comment: Assuming `string` is `std::string` and not a typedef for a char array, it would be `name.pop_back()`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks, didn't notice he was using a string.